# Compare two cells and run different code based on comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my code to compare cells using an If statement. When the cells are not equal, I want to run my other code.

It is showing red on my screen when I try to do the Else If statement.

```
Dim WS1 As Worksheet: Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Increments")
Dim WS2 As Worksheet: Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, WS1_Cell As Range, WS2_Cell As Range

LR1 = WS1.Range("S" & WS1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = WS2.Range("H" & WS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each WS1_Cell In WS1.Range("S1:S" & LR1)
    For Each WS2_Cell In WS2.Range("H1:H" & LR2)
        Else If WS1_Cell = WS2_Cell Then
            WS2_Cell.Offset(, 5).Value = WS1_Cell.Offset(, 5).Value
                Next WS2_Cell
Next WS1_Cell

       Else  WS1_Cell <> WS2_Cell Then

Dim wsCopy2 As Worksheet
Dim wsDest2 As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow2 As Long
Dim lDestLastRow2 As Long
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy2 = Worksheets("Increments")
  Set wsDest2 = Worksheets("Output")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column S
  lCopyLastRow2 = wsCopy2.Cells(wsCopy2.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column H
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow2 = wsDest2.Cells(wsDest2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data if match not found
  wsCopy2.Range("S3:X" & lCopyLastRow2).COPY
     wsDest2.Range("H" & lDestLastRow2).PasteSpecial xlValues

   End If
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here.  Are you asking how to resolve the 2 syntax errors?

Comment: yes. i believe so. sorry really new to vba. it is showing red on my screen when i try to do the else if statement

Comment: You have an `Else If` come out of nowhere inside a `For` loop. You really need to sort your statements and fix your indentation. It's there for a reason.